# Smallest Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: probability, information-theory, kullback-leibler

Suppose we seek to approximate an arbitrary distribution $p_1(x)$ by a normal
$p_2(x) \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \Sigma)$. How can I show that the values that lead to the smallest Kullback–Leibler
divergence are:
$$
\mu_1 = \mathbb E_1[X]
$$
and
$$
\Sigma_1 = \mathbb E_1[(X − \mu)(X − \mu)^T],
$$
where the notation $\mathbb E_1(\cdot)$ indicates the expectation is taken over the density $p_1(x)$?

For reference, the definition of Kullback–Leibler divergence is
$$
    D( p_1 \|\; p_2) = \int p_1 \log(p_1/p_2) \text{d}\lambda \> .
$$

Comment: I have tried to edit your question to use $\LaTeX$ math notation. I've also tweaked the wording a little bit. Please make sure I have not inadvertently introduced errors. Cheers. :)

Comment: One doubt: I'm not quite sure what your title for the question is supposed to be getting at. Can you explain briefly?

Comment: All Im trying to say is that the difference between two distributions in the same space is the
Kullback-Leibler divergence.

Comment: I guess that depends on what you mean by "difference". :)

Comment: I guess the divergence is not a metric on the space of distributions, right?

Answer (score 11):

If you express the Kullback–Leibler divergence when $p_2$ is a normal pdf on $\mathbb R^d$,
\begin{align}
D&(p_1||p_2) =\int_{\mathbb R^d} p_1 \log p_1 \text{d}\lambda - \int_{\mathbb R^d} p_1 \log p_2 \text{d}\lambda\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^d} p_1 \log p_1 \text{d}\lambda - \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb R^d} p_1 \left\{-(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) - \log |\Sigma| -d \log 2\pi \right\}  \text{d}\lambda \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^d} p_1 \log p_1 \text{d}\lambda + \dfrac{1}{2} \left\{ \log |\Sigma| + d \log 2\pi + \mathbb{E}_1 \left[ (x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) \right] \right\}
\end{align}
Now
$$
\mathbb{E}_1 \left[ (x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) \right]=
\mathbb{E}_1 \left[ (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x] )^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x]) \right]$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad + (\mathbb{E}_1[x]-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbb{E}_1[x]-\mu)
$$
so the minimum in $\mu$ is indeed reached for $\mu=\mathbb{E}_1[x]$.

Minimising
$$
\log |\Sigma| + \mathbb{E}_1 \left[ (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x] )^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x]) \right] =
$$
$$
\log |\Sigma| + \mathbb{E}_1 \left[ \text{trace} \left\{ (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x] )^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x]) \right\}\right] = \qquad\qquad\qquad
$$
$$
\log |\Sigma| + \mathbb{E}_1 \left[ \text{trace} \left\{ \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x]) (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x] )^T  \right\}\right] =
$$
$$
\log |\Sigma| + \text{trace} \left\{ \Sigma^{-1} \mathbb{E}_1 \left[  (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x]) (x-\mathbb{E}_1[x] )^T  \right] \right\}=
$$
$$
\qquad\qquad \log |\Sigma| + \text{trace} \left\{ \Sigma^{-1} \Sigma_1 \right\}
$$
leads to a minimum in $\Sigma$ for $\Sigma=\Sigma_1$.